# Dereferencing value in variable as pointer address

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Why is it that only pointers can be dereferenced. When we have a character pointer, lets say "p" and we do a "*p" operation, it means go fetch the contents of the address location stored in p. In the end what we are asking here is to go and fetch the contents of a "certain value" by treating this value as address.

Now assume that an integer pointer "p" that takes 8 bytes in certain architecture. Assume "p" holds the address of an integer variable "a"(int *p = &a). Now if I have a variable "x" of size uint64_t, then essentially this variable can hold 8 bytes of data. i.e. "memcpy(&x, &p, 8)", I am copying the address location stored in "p" to "x". In c programming we can dereference a pointer using "*p" and we get the value of "a". Why is it that we cannot do something like *((int*)x) and get the value of "a".

Comment: Please format you code as code.

Comment: You can do `*(int*)x`, that is, tell the compiler to pretend that that integer value is a pointer, and dereference it.

Comment: technically any number can be used as a pointer. after all, a pointer is really just a number representing a memory address. but you still have to tell the compiler to treat that number as a pointer, because "2 as memory address" and "2 as integer" as essentially indistinguishable. they're both just numbers. it's the CONTEXT in which you're using them that matters.

Comment: And because pointers also have a type. You theoretically can dereference anything you want, even a 8-byte string interpreted as your `uint64_t`, but it may (and most likely will) lead you to many problems.

Comment: If you access hardware or configure a CPU it's often done by accessing specific addresses which are hard coded numerical values in the program and then assigned to pointers, and then dereferenced through the pointers. I think that just casting is an equivalent conversion.

Comment: I just realized that *(int*)x works when x is of type uint64_t. However if x is of type double and double also holds 8 bytes, I get compilation error saying "error: operand of type 'double' cannot be cast to a pointer type"

Answer (score 4):

You **can** do `*(int*)x`, and it will fetch the `int` at memory location `x`. I don't think this is officially supported in the C standard, but in practice it *usually* works on *most* implementations.

Part of the point of the type system is to stop you from making mistakes. *Usually* you don't want to dereference a `uint64_t`, so if you do it's probably because you made a mistake, and the compiler will point out the mistake for you.

By the way, `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer type that's the same size of a pointer. Don't rely on `uint64_t` being the same size as a pointer, if you ever want to be able to run your code on another CPU architecture.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is important.  Also, C++ is much, much more type safe than C.  This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Because C++ is not assembly language. In assembly you can do whatever you want with the registers - you can 'dereference' them (use as indirect operands) or multiply. Chip could not care less.

C++, as a high level language, aims to help developer. If you want something to be a dereferencable address, you type it as such, and C++ prevents you from accidentally doing something which you can't do with an address. This is a very big advantage.